# Java Replace Character At Specific Position Of String?

Tags: java, string, replace, char

I am trying to replace a character at a specific position of a string.

For example:

```
String str = "hi";
```

replace string position #2 (i) to another letter "k"

How would I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 56):

**[Petar Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791998/petar-ivanov)'s answer to [replace a character at a specific index in a string question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/java-replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string/6952379#6952379)**

String are immutable in Java. You can't change them.

You need to create a new string with the character replaced.

```
String myName = "domanokz";
String newName = myName.substring(0,4)+'x'+myName.substring(5);
```

Or you can use a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder("domanokz");
myName.setCharAt(4, 'x');

System.out.println(myName);
```

Answer (score 18):

Kay!
First of all, when dealing with strings you have to refer to their positions in 0 base convention. This means that if you have a string like this:

```
String str = "hi";
//str length is equal 2 but the character
//'h' is in the position 0 and character 'i' is in the postion 1
```

With that in mind, the best way to tackle this problem is creating a method to replace a character at a given position in a string like this:

**Method:**

```
public String changeCharInPosition(int position, char ch, String str){
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    charArray[position] = ch;
    return new String(charArray);
}
```

**Then you should call the method 'changeCharInPosition' in this way:**

```
String str = "hi";
str = changeCharInPosition(1, 'k', str);
System.out.print(str); //this will return "hk"
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate, post something!

Comment: Does this one let you replace the character with nothing (empty/remove it)?

Comment: What you mean by nothing? An empty string or a string of blank spaces?

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking. Obviously an empty string `""` could be used as the argument to `ch`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! @trusktr

Answer (score 16):

Use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.setCharAt(i - 1, 'k');
str = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 14):

To replace a character at a specified position :

```
public static String replaceCharAt(String s, int pos, char c) {
   return s.substring(0,pos) + c + s.substring(pos+1);
}
```

Comment: Worked for me to replace few char from a position.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to re-use a string, then use *StringBuffer*:

```
String str = "hi";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
while (...) {
    sb.setCharAt(1, 'k');
}
```

**EDIT:**

Note that *StringBuffer* is thread-safe, while using *StringBuilder* is faster, but not thread-safe.