# Java - Character replacement in a string

Tags: java

I'm having some troubles the replacement of a character in a string. The code works perfectly fine for the removal of hyphens an periods, however for the letter 'e' it removes the 'e' in "test", and it also converts the three 'e's at the end of the string. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
        String str = "This is a test string, 12345! -12e3.0 eee";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if((str.charAt(i) == '-') && (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i+1)))) {
            str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), '*');
        }

        if((str.charAt(i) == 'e') && (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i+1)))) {
            str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), '*');
        }

        if((str.charAt(i) == '.') && (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i+1)))) {
            str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), '*');
        }
    }
    str = str.replaceAll("[1234567890]", "*");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Perhaps you should write out the contents of `str` at the end of the for-loop.  Then you can see what happens when.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what you should expect: it replaces all 'e's with '*'s.

Comment: Unrelated you may have an issue if i is the last character and you try to evaluate str.charAt(i+1)

Comment: Do you want your program fixed, or is it OK to show a simpler solution?

Comment: Logical ANDs must both be true for the answer to be true though.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/java-replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each case, the `if` part just finds whether the character should be replaced... but then the replacement itself:

```
str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), '*')
```

... performs that replacement *for the whole of the string*.

The simplest fix to this is probably to convert it to an array of characters to start with, replace one character at a time, and then create a string for the rest:

```
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length - 1; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == '-' && Character.isDigit(chars[i + 1])) {
        chars[i] = '*';
    }
    // Similarly for the other two
}
String newString = new String(chars);
```

Or to avoid the duplication, replace the middle section with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length - 1; i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(chars[i + 1]) &&
        (chars[i] == '-' || chars[i] == 'e' || chars[i] == '.')) {
        chars[i] = '*';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace(str.charAt(i), '*');` will replace all characters.  [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

You can use a StringBuilder to replace a specific character in a String.  Please review this question and answer.

[Replace a character at a specific index in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/java-replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string/6952379#6952379)