# How to replace character at particular index in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android. I have a string containing huge data. In that string I want to replace a particular character to another character. I got the index of the character which I want to replace. But I am unable to replace that character.
How can I do that?

```
String str = "data1data2mdata2test1test2test3dd" 

int ind = str.indexOf("m");
System.out.println("the index of m" + ind);
```

Now in the above string I want to replace the character "m"(after data2) to "#".

Now how can I replace the m to #. Please help me in this reagard.

Comment: Don't forget to search first : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/java-replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substring`:

```
String newStr = str.substring(0, ind) + '#' + str.substring(ind + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`str = str.replaceFirst("m", "#");`

It will replace the first m to #

Comment: Question was about index

Comment: Yes, but if you read the question description, apparently the challenge is about to replace a particular character to another one.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str1 = "data1data2mdata2test1test2test3dd"

    String str = str1.replace("m", "#");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: `replace` returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

Comment: Yaa Boris I forgot to mention here,It can achieve this in such a way: StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("data1data2mdata2test1test2test3dd");
str.setCharAt(9, '#');

System.out.println(str);

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting 10 as system out,
so this way you can replace it like,

```
Str.replace('m', '#')--->when you want all occurrences of it to replace it,
```

Or if you want only first occurrence to be replaced by # then you can do following trick,

```
StringBuffer buff=new StringBuffer();
buff.append(Str.substring(0,ind)).append("#").append(Str.substring(ind+1));
```

i hope it would help