# Java replacing char at index

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm wanting to replace a character at in a string

Comment: Use String.substring() method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - replace a character at a specific index in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/java-replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use the utility class StringBuilder like this:

```
    StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder(captureString[0]);
    char replaceMe = captureString[0].charAt(strOneRand);
    resultString.setCharAt(strOneRand, Character.toUpperCase(replaceMe));

    System.out.println(resultString.toString());
```

The assignment is just for clarification, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by using `substring()` to pick apart and recreate the string, but another way is to just convert it to a `char[]` and operate on that, e.g.:

```
char[] data = captureString[0].toCharArray();
data[strOneRand] = Character.toUpperCase(data[strOneRand]); // or whatever
String outputFinal = new String(data);
```

An example of accomplishing this with `substring()` can be found in the accepted answer of [Replace a character at a specific index in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/java-replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string). An example of doing it with a `StringBuilder` can be found there as well.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to do this

```
char[] charArray = captureString[0].toCharArray();
charArray[strOneRand] = THE_NEW_CHARECTOR_YOU_WANT_TO_REPLACE;
String outputFinal = String.copyValueOf(charArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = captureString[0].substring(0,strOneRand);
String b = captureString[0].substring(strOneRand,strOneRand+1).toUpperCase;
String c = captureString[0].substring(strOneRand+1);

System.out.println(a+b+c);
```

replace method will make the first occurrence of chosen character to upper case.
if input string is "aaaaa", you will always get "Aaaaa".

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do in your situation:

```
public void replaceChar(String strPassed, int index){

    char strArray[] = strPassed.toCharArray(); 
    strArray[index] = (char)(strArray[index] - 32);
    strPassed[0] = new String(strArray);

}
```

and then wherever I wanted to convert the character into UpperCase:

```
replaceChar(capturString[0], strOneRand);
```