# How to make alternate characters in a string to uppercase?

Tags: java, string

I wrote the following code but similar characters are always in the same case. What's wrong in this code and How can this problem be solved??

```
private void genBTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    String str = new String(strTF.getText());
    int n = str.length();
    char ch;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            ch = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));
            str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), ch);
        } else {
            ch = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i));
            str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), ch);
        }
    }
    jumTF.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: `replace` works on the whole String.

Comment: `replace(oldChar, newChar)` returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar. What you want is to [replace a character at a specific location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/java-replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string).

Comment: You should work out things like this in a command line app. before worrying about how to get them to work in a GUI.  And on that note, 'changing case in a string'  has nothing to do with either Swing or your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your program you were using replace() which replaces  characters/CharSequences in the whole input what you need to do is

- Put the string into an array.
- Iterate over said array.
- convert that array back into string

  > private void genBTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  >
  > ```
  > String str = new String(strTF.getText());
  > char [] chr= str.toCharArray();
  > int n = chr.length;
  > char ch;
  > int i;
  > for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  >     if(i % 2 == 0) {
  >         ch = Character.toLowerCase(chr[i]);
  >        chr[i]=ch;
  >     } else {
  >         ch = Character.toUpperCase(chr[i]);
  >      chr[i]=ch;
  >     }
  > }
  > jumTF.setText(new String(chr)); }
  > ```

hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 6):

Unlike what its name says, `.replace()` replaces characters/`CharSequence`s in the *whole* input. The difference with `.replaceAll()` is that it takes literals as arguments and not regexes/regex replacements strings (and that it has an overload taking two `char`s as arguments). That is the second worst misnamed method of the `String` class after `matches()`.

Moreover you create a new `String` on each character you replace, so you have n+1 strings for a n character long string. Do it like this instead:

```
final char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

final int len = chars.length;

char c;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    c = chars[i];

    chars[i] = i % 2 == 0
        ? Character.toLowerCase(c)
        : Character.toUpperCase(c);
}

jumTF.setText(new String(chars));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **String** are *immutable* in java , you can use **StringBuilder or StringBuffer** to solve this problem

```
StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder(inputString);
```

You can use your own logic just with slight change  instead of using

```
str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), ch);//since  it replaces in whole string
```

Use

```
str.setCharAt(i,ch);
```

So your final Program looks like this :

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            ch = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));
            str.setCharAt(i,ch);
        } else {
            ch = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i));
            str.setCharAt(i,ch);
        }
    }
```

Suppose InputString is : `stackoverflow`
then output is : `sTaCkOvErFlOw`