# Output for Converting a number in decimal into its Complement

Tags: java, string

Output for converting a number in decimal into its 1s complement  and then again converting the number into decimal does not come as expected.

MyApproach

I first converted the number from decimal to binary. Replaced all Os with 1 and *vice versa* and then converted the number into decimal.

Can anyone guide me? What I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
public static int complimentDecimal(int num) {
    int p = 0;
    String s1 = "";
    // Convert Decimal to Binary

    while (num > 0) {
        p = num % 2;
        s1 = p + s1;
        num = num / 2;
    }
    System.out.println(s1);
    // Replace the 0s with 1s and 1s with 0s
    for (int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++) {
        if (s1.charAt(j) == 0) {
            s1.replace(s1.charAt(j), '1');
        } else {
            s1.replace(s1.charAt(j), '0');
        }

    }
    System.out.println(s1);

    int decimal = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (int m = s1.length() - 1; m >= 0; m--) {
        decimal += (s1.charAt(m) * Math.pow(2, k));

        k++;
    }
    return decimal;
}
```

Comment: _Note:Please don't post alternate approaches approaches._ why not?

Comment: @Pétur I want to try that myself.My homework.I need to do it.I will ask as A separate thread.If I didn't get

Comment: @Everyone Explained So Perfectly.Now,I am confused who is the best. :P +1 for all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to define the amount of Bits your binary representation should have or an complement representation does not make sense.

If you convert `100` the binary is `1100100`
complement is `0011011` which is `27`
now convert `27`. Binary is `11011`, complement `00100` which is `4`.

Now define yourself a Bit length of 8.
`100` is `01100100`, complement `10011011`, is `155`
`155` is `10011011`, complement `01100100`, is `100`
Works because every binary representation has a length of 8 bits. This is absolutly necessary for the whole complement thing to make any sense.
Consider that you now have a limit for numbers that are convertable.
`11111111` which is `255`.

Now that we talked about that I will correct your code

```
static int MAX_BITS = 8;
static int MAX_INT = (int)Math.pow(2, MAX_BITS) - 1;

public static int complimentDecimal(int num)
{
    // check if number is to high for the bitmask
    if(num > MAX_INT){
        System.out.println("Number=" + num + " to high for MAX_BITS="+MAX_BITS);
        return -1;
    }

    // Your conversion works!
    int p=0;
    String s1="";
    //Convert Decimal to Binary
    while(num>0)
    {
        p=num%2;
        s1=p+s1;
        num=num/2;
    }

    // fill starting zeros to match MAX_BITS length
    while(s1.length() < MAX_BITS)
        s1 = "0" + s1;

    System.out.println(s1);

    //Replace the 0s with 1s and 1s with 0s

    // your approach on that is very wrong
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int j=0;j<s1.length();j++){
        if(s1.charAt(j)=='0') sb.append("1");
        else if(s1.charAt(j)=='1') sb.append("0");
    }
    s1 = sb.toString();

    /*
    for(int j=0;j<s1.length();j++)
    {
        if(s1.charAt(j)==0)
        {
            s1.replace(s1.charAt(j),'1');
        }
        else
        {
            s1.replace(s1.charAt(j),'0');
        }

    }
    */
    System.out.println(s1);

    int decimal=0;
    int k=0;
    for(int m=s1.length()-1;m>=0;m--)
    {
        // you don't want the char code here but the int value of the char code
        //decimal += (s1.charAt(m) * Math.pow(2, k));
        decimal+=(Character.getNumericValue(s1.charAt(m))*Math.pow(2, k));

        k++;
    } 
    return decimal;
}
```

Additional Note: Don't get bigger then MAX_BITS = 31 or you need to work with long instead of int in your method.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: @ArcticLord Why you converted s1=sb.toString().We can do the same thing on sb also?

Comment: You could, but it is better practise to build up a `String` with [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and when you finish store it as a `String` using the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to assign the replaced String to the already defined variable that is,

```
s1.replace(s1.charAt(j),'1');
```

it should be

```
s1 = s1.replace(s1.charAt(j),'1');
```

and the next case is, when you are changing in that order it would change all the characters similar to matched case 
refer [Replace a character at a specific index in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

The problem (OK, one of the problems) is here:

```
if(s1.charAt(j)==0)
```

Characters in Java are actually integers, in the range 0 to 65535.  Each of those numbers actually means the character corresponding to that number in the Unicode chart.  The character `'0'` has the value 48, not 0.  So when you've created a string of `'0'` and `'1'` characters, the characters will have the integer values 48 and 49.  Naturally, when you compare this to the integer 0, you'll get `false` no matter what.

Try

```
if(s1.charAt(j)=='0')
```

(**Note:** OK, the other answer is right--`replace` does not work.  Not only are you using it incorrectly, by not assigning the result, it's not the right method anyway, because `s1.replace(s1.charAt(j),'1')` replaces all `'0'` with `'1'` characters; it doesn't replace character `j`. If you specifically want to replace the j'th character in a `String` with something else, you'll need to use `substring()` and build a new string, not `replace()`.)

A couple other things to note: (1) Integers are not "decimal" or "binary".  When your method gets the `num` parameter, this is just a number, not a decimal number or a binary number.  It's represented in your computer as a binary number (unless you're using something like a Burroughs 3500, but I think all of those died before Java was invented).  But it really isn't considered decimal, binary, octal, hex, ternary, or whatever, until you do something that converts it to a `String`.  (2) I know you said not to post alternative approaches, but you could replace the entire method with just one line: `return ~num;`.  That complements all the bits.  If you were thinking that you couldn't do this because `num` was a decimal number, see #1.  (3) "Compliment" means to say something nice about somebody.  If you're talking about flipping all the bits, the correct spelling is "complement".

Answer (score 1):

`String.Replace(oldChar, newChar)` method returns a `new` string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in given string with newChar. It does not perform change on the given string.