# Replacing a single character of a string

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea

I am trying to replace only one character of a string. But whenever the character has multiple occurrences within the string, all of those characters are being replaced, while I only want the particular character to be replaced. For example:

```
    String str = "hello world";
    str = str.replace(str.charAt(2), Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(2)));
    System.out.println(str);
```

Gives the result:

```
heLLo worLd
```

while I want it to be:

```
heLlo world
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: See this Link for several methods on how to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **replace** will not work because it replace all the occurrence in the string. Also **replaceFirst** will not work as it will always remove
>   the first occurrence.

As Strings are non mutable , so in either way you need create a new string always. Can be done by either of the following.

- Use substring, and manually create the string that you want.

  ```
  int place = 2;
  str = str.substring(0,place)+Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(place))+str.substring(place+1);
  ```
- Convert the string to array of characters and replace any character that you want by using index, and then convert array back to the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `StringBuilder` instead of `String` to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

`replace(char, char)` will replace all occurrences of the specified `char`, not only the char at the index. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

You can do something like

```
String str = "hello world";
String newStr = str.substring(0, 2) + Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(2)) + str.substring(3);
```

Comment: didn't work, because character at location 1 will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "hello world";
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    charArray[2] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[2]);
    str = new String(charArray);
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works too

```
     String str = "hello world";
     str = str.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(str.charAt(2)),
            String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(2))));
     System.out.println(str);
```