# Replace the character ‘e’ with ‘E’ in a word “Hello” in java

Tags: java

I want to replace the character ‘e’ with ‘E’ in a word “Hello”. I'm reading the arguments from the prompt.

```
class LowToUpCase{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length != 0) {
            String str = args[0];
            str = str.substring(1,2);
            System.out.println(str.toUpperCase());  
        }else{
            System.out.println("Give arguments");
        }
    }
}
```

Im getting the output as the Capitalised E only. But I'm not getting any idea  how to get the output as hEllo . Please give me the hint to get the needed output.

Comment: [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) might be good for you.

Comment: He should use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of StringBuffer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string.

Comment: @Casey Oh, right. My bad.

Comment: How should your program behave if the input is something other than Hello?  Should it convert all e characters to E, or only the second character of the input?  And what if the input is only a single letter?

Answer (score 4):

Why not `replace` the lower case `e` with its uppercase counterpart?

```
String str = args[0];
str = str.replace('e', 'E');
System.out.println(str);
```

[Docs for `String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)).

Comment: Thank you Sir !. I got the Output. I am a beginner in Java. Again Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Boann Sorry for ironing over your edit, `replace` is the better choice here of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the replace() method from the String class.

```
class LowToUpCase{

   public static void main(String[] args){

   if (args.length != 0)
    {
      String str = args[0];
      str = str.replace('e', 'E');
      System.out.println(str);

    }else{
    System.out.println("Give arguments");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of TimoSta's earlier answer?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that, he replied while I was writing mine.

Answer (score 2):

It *appears* that you also want to *lowercase* (at least) the *first letter* (so don't forget to call `toLowerCase()` on the input). I would prefer a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (a *mutable* sequence of characters over modifying an *immutable* `String`) and something like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(args[0].toLowerCase());
sb.replace(1, 2, sb.substring(1, 2).toUpperCase());
System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="Hello";
String value=s.replace( 'e' ,'E');
```