# java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unexpected type

Tags: java, android, string

This program converts from hexadecimal to binary.
This is my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int nh = 0, k = 0, j = 0, w = 0, z = 0, lun = 0, r;
    String line;
    String nb = null;
    char nhc = 0;
    BufferedReader tastiera = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Inserire il numero in esadecimale");
    line = tastiera.readLine();
    lun = line.length();
    System.out.println(line);
    if (lun > 1) {
        lun--;
    }
    for (z = lun; z > 0; z--)
        nhc = line.charAt(z);
    {
        if (nhc == 'a' || nhc == 'A') {
            nhc = 10;
        }
        if (nhc == 'b' || nhc == 'B') {
            nhc = 11;
        }
        if (nhc == 'c' || nhc == 'C') {
            nhc = 12;
        }
        if (nhc == 'd' || nhc == 'D') {
            nhc = 13;
        }
        if (nhc == 'e' || nhc == 'E') {
            nhc = 14;
        }
        if (nhc == 'f' || nhc == 'F') {
            nhc = 15;
        }
        for (k = nhc, w = 0; k > 0 && w < lun * 4; k = k / 2, w++) {
            nb.charAt(w) = k % 2;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Il numero binario è " + nb);
}
```

This appear when I run:

```
Inserire il numero in esadecimale
12
12
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unexpected type
>     required: variable
>     found:    value
>       at esadecimale.binario.EsadecimaleBinario.main(EsadecimaleBinario.java:56)
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: run:
Inserire il numero in esadecimale
12
12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unexpected type
  required: variable
  found:    value
 at esadecimale.binario.EsadecimaleBinario.main(EsadecimaleBinario.java:56)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: you can´t do `nb.charAt(w) = k % 2;`.

Comment: run:
Inserire il numero in esadecimale
12
12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unexpected type
  required: variable
  found:    value
 at esadecimale.binario.EsadecimaleBinario.main(EsadecimaleBinario.java:56)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: kevin why??????????????

Comment: because `nb.charAt(w)` doesn´t represent a variable. And as you do assign and don´t have a variable this results in invalid code. This could be answered by different Questions here. for Example, java is [pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), so in generall the idea you had wont work for it. Addtionally [Strings in java are immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java), so you can´t just change the existing `String`, but need to reassign the one you want to change.

Comment: sorry,I'm new on java what I have to do to fix

Comment: nb.charAt(w) represent  the position on the string

Comment: If you paste messages that refers to line number, please indicate which line contains error, or paste the whole class so that we can check it by ourselves.
You could also try to compile first, then run. In such case you'll have a compilation result, that is better readable than RuntimeError.

Comment: I writed as //  in the code

Comment: I can't see // in the code. Am I blind?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this assignment: `nb.charAt(w)= k%2;` 
That's a value on the left hand side ( chartAt(index) returns a character ) and it can't be assigned to. That's what is happening at runtime...

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string). Hope it makes sense.

Comment: How I can fix it?

Comment: Try something like this: 

StringBuilder nb = new StringBuilder("");
nb.setCharAt(w, (char) k%2);