# Anonymizing the xml: how to remove data while leaving the tags in Java?

Tags: java, regex, xml

Given an xml structure in a String type, I'm looking for a way to replace data with four asterisks, while leaving the tags in their place. That is, starting from this

```
<one> <two> abc </two> <two> def </two> </one>
```

I want it to become

```
<one> <two> **** </two> <two> **** </two> </one>
```

I've tried

```
requestBody.replaceAll(">[^<]+?<","> **** <")
```

but I'm also capturing any blank spaces between two adjacent tags, having therefore

```
<one> **** <two> **** </two> **** <two> **** </two> **** </one>
```

How could I achieve my goal? Any suggestions?

[Here](https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/31) for some tests.

## Edit

Following Michael Kay suggestions I've found this solution

```
/**
 * Anonimyzes an xml structure replacing all data between tags with 4 asterisks. 
 * Tags won't be replaced.
 * 
 * @param xmlInput the string representing the xml to be anonymized
 * @return the anonymized xml structure.
 */
private String anonymizeXml(String xmlInput){
    String anonimizedXml=null;
    try {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new StringReader("<xsl:transform version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"><xsl:template match=\"*\">  <xsl:copy>   <xsl:apply-templates/>  </xsl:copy></xsl:template><xsl:template match=\"text()[normalize-space()]\"> **** </xsl:template></xsl:transform>"));
        Transformer transformer;
        transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        Source text = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlInput));
        
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(writer));
        anonimizedXml = writer.toString();
        
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return anonimizedXml;
}
```

Comment: Thou shall not parse XML or any other tree-like grammar with regular expressions. Or in other words, wrong tool for the job. Use an XML parser to locate and replace all text nodes.

Comment: @tucuxi could you be a bit more specific? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for a very simple XSLT transformation:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]">****</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

This task is a bit too heavy for a single RegExp. You could use one RegExp to find the place including the tags:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[a-z]>[^<]+?</[a-z]>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlString);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(xmlString.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
}
```

Would print:

```
<two> abc </two>
<two> def </two>
```

After saving the positions of each match you can use your original RegExp to look for the positions to replace in the substrings. The start position of your first match added to the positions of the substring match will give you the positions to replace in the xmlString.

When you have all positions you can start replacing parts of the xmlString [using substring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6952379/4622673). Make sure to replace the last match first since the positions of the later parts would change each time you replaced an earlier part.