# Printing a double value with 2 decimals with a . not a ,

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a little problem in an app I am working on. I am using some double values and I want to place them in some `TextViews`, but when the number is placed, instead of "." it appears ",". I would like to have a dot so I can import the value with a `substring`.

```
DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
final TextView totalPrice = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.actualPrice);
double price = 200.12357123;
totalPrice.setText("$" + precision.format(price));
```

Inside the `TextView` will appear 200,12 and I would like to appear 200.12, so I can convert the text in a double value later on.

Comment: But your code is working in my project just removing  getView().

Comment: @DileepPatel The result what `DecimalFormat` creates depends on the user-specific `Locale`.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifications.

Comment: Set the `Locale` to one with [dot as decimal separator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
String formatString = "#,###,###,###.##";
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatString, otherSymbols);

double price = 200.12357123;

Log.i("TAG", "" + "$ " + df.format(price));
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Same result mate :(

Comment: This is what the op already did. Please read carefully the question.

Comment: @Andy95 please check my answer.

Comment: @devpuh Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will give an exactly same answer as you want:

```
double price = 200.12357123;
String s=String.format(Locale.US, "$%.2f", price);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change the '.' with ',' ,when you want to convert to double.

Comment: How exactly I do that?

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string