# toUpperCase at specific index uppercases more chars than supposed to

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to solve a problem that takes specific symbols and removes them from the string, then it converts the character following that symbol to uppercase. But for some reason characters after the uppercased characters are also getting uppercased.

`s` is the given string.

```
String[] symbols = { "-", "_" };
int index = 0;   

for(String symbol : symbols) {
  while(s.indexOf(symbol) >= 0){
    index = s.indexOf(symbol);
    s = s.replaceFirst(symbol, "");
    s = s.replace(s.charAt(index), Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(index)));
    System.out.println(index);
  }
}
```

The given input is: `river_Green_Green_Wall_Lake_left_Samurai_Wall`

What I expected was: `riverGreenGreenWallLakeLeftSamuraiWall`

But what I got instead is: `riverGreenGreenWaLLLakeLeftSamuraiWaLL`

Comment: The method ```replace``` replaces all occurrences of the given string. This is not what you want. Since there is no ```replaceFirst``` with a starting index, you might need to use some ```substring``` calls in combination with it to achieve your goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a character at a specific index in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string)

Comment: Thank you @Islingre, using substring to capitalize worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than using replace, you should try rebuilding the string with the index uppercased

```
    for(String symbol : symbols) {
      while(s.indexOf(symbol) >= 0){
        index = s.indexOf(symbol);
        //
        s = s.substring(0,index)+s.substring(index+1,index+2).toUpperCase()+s.substring(index+2);
        //
        System.out.println(s);
      }
    }
```

Comment: It would be better to do this with a `StringBuilder`, since this would avoid continually rebuilding and discarding the string: you can use `StringBuilder.indexOf` to find the character, and then `StringBuilder.set` to change it.

Answer (score 1):

just you need call replace method in the same line when you replace symbol:

```
    String s ="river_Green_Green_Wall_Lake_left_Samurai_Wall";
    String[] symbols = { "-", "_" };
    int index = 0;

  for(String symbol : symbols) {
     while(s.indexOf(symbol) >= 0){
       index = s.indexOf(symbol);
       s = s.replaceFirst(symbol, "").replace(s.charAt(index) ,Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(index)));
      }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```