# Error at using Assignment operator in java

Tags: java, string

I also the error "Left Hand Side of an Assignment must be a Variable" for following line

```
outPutArray.charAt(i)=inputArray[i]
```

how to resolve this? I have tried putting braces like but of no use

```
(outPutArray.charAt(i))=inputArray[i]
```

Comment: Strings in java are immutable. And even then, `charAt` returns a `char`. You can't assign to it. It would be like writing `'a' = 'b';`.

Comment: if outPutArray is also an array you can just `outPutArray[i]=inputArray[i]`

Comment: @Conffusion as `outPutArray` is calling `.charAt()` it is most likely a String...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mutate a String object. This is not possible, String is supposed to be immutable. You have to create a new String with the changed content, use a char array instead, or something else that allows you to actually achieve what you are trying to do in the end (which is: given an input String, return an output String where one character is changed).

With that out of the way, you can't do an assignment on the return value of a function. You don't get a reference back that you can change and then some variable gets changed. You get a value back. The great [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1) question is maybe a good read.

Answer (score 0):

Very silly, but the format should be:

```java
inputArray[i] = outPutArray.charAt(i);
```

not

```java
outPutArray.charAt(i) = inputArray[i]
```

putting the function on the left hand side means you are assigning a **constant integer** to a **integer array element**. As the integer is constant, it will fail. This is why we put our variables(inputArray[i] in your case) on the left hand side and our functions on the right hand(outPutArray.charAt(i)). Hope you understand!

Comment: `inputArray[i] = outPutArray.charAt(i);` to be fair, this is an assumption *you* are making. I mean, you are giving a syntactically correct piece of code, but you're assuming that's what OP is trying to do, which is not so obvious.

Comment: Additionally, where is the "constant integer" and "integer array element" coming from?

Comment: The constant integer is coming from the return value of ```outputarray.charAt(i)```. All numbers(0, 1, 2, 3, e.g.) are all constant, they do **not** change. You can make variables have that value, but you can't assign variables or constants to a constant. Once again: **they do not change**;

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it is not a assumption. If it is a array, it is a array of variables. The variables can be a function, integer, float, even class! A function returns void, or a constant(1, 2, 3 for integer, 0.0, 0.1 for floats)

Comment: @codernaut1 I believe maloomeister had a problem not with the "constant" part but with you calling them "integer", which is somehow correct (`char`s are integer numbers) but it's weird to use that term when `char` was right there for the taking.

Comment: @codernaut1 yours is an assumption because OP was trying to assign A to B and you assumed they were trying to assign B to A when it's much more likely they're just using the wrong syntax.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Oh ok. @maloomeister, a char can be displayed as a character("a") or a integer through 0 and 255. You might see the integer form of a char by this ```javascript"\x00"```.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ill not try to get into a argument but ik it is a syntax error, wrong orientation of assignment

Comment: @codernaut1 of course it is a syntax error while yours is *syntactically* correct, I'm not questioning that. What I'm questioning is your assumption that the code you provided is *semantically* correct.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thank you for mentioning that. My explaining is not the best(proved by my parents and teachers). But let's close this argument ok? I will fix my answer later if that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

.charAt(i) function returns the character at position i. It does not return the reference to the character at that index.
[Look at this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string)