# about multiple markers error on str.charAt(i) with operators

Tags: java

```
package com.chapter.BJ.UpperLower;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) >= 65 && str.charAt(i) <= 90) {
                str.charAt(i) += 32;
            } else if (str.charAt(i) <= 122 && str.charAt(i) >= 97) {
                str.charAt(i) -= 32;
            }
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Hello everyone, I don't understand why I get an error on `str.charAt(i) += 32;` and `str.charAt(i) -= 32;`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: add the error stack trace in the question.

Comment: As specified in the Java Language Specification [15.26. Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26-200): "**The result of the first operand of an assignment operator must be a variable, or a compile-time error occurs.**" -  `...charAt(i)` is calling a method and it results in a value and not a variable (( also be aware that a string is immutable, it can not be changed - a new `String` must be created, or use a `StringBuilder` - I would also have a look at the documentation of `Character`, it may have some useful methods ))

Answer (score 0):

`str.charAt(i)` merely returns the character at that index. I assume you want to alter the character at that index, so what you are looking for is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

The `charAt()` method simply returns the character at the specified index in a string. Its source code is below. It is an R-value and can be only used on the right side of assignment statements. But `str.charAt(i) += 32;` is equivalent to `str.charAt(i) = str.charAt(i) + 32;`, so you may get expected variable error.

```
public char charAt(int index) {
   if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
   }
   return value[index];
}
```

You can introduce a local variable to store `stc.charAt(i)` and update it as you need, like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (str.charAt(i) >= 65 && str.charAt(i) <= 90) {
        c += 32;
    } else if (str.charAt(i) <= 122 && str.charAt(i) >= 97) {
        c -= 32;
    }
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

If you need to update `str` simultaneously, consider `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` since `String` is an immutable object.

Comment: **On a side:** If you have established that `c = str.charAt(i);` then you no longer need the `str.charAt(i)` calls within the `if` and `else` statements, just using `c` will do: `if (c >= 65 && c <= 90) {`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Yes, it is a cleaner way.